# Firefox Clear Web Console keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to clear the Firefox Web Console?

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Keyboard_shortcuts, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> should work, but it does not work on MacOS / Firefox 60.0a1

Comment: Could be a typo? Try <cmd>+<L>.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> seems to work, but only when the cursor is positioned inside the console input. Otherwise, it doesn't work in my machine. I am using Firefox 58.0.1 on a Mac.

> [image: cursor positioned in console input]